# Поставить объект в нулевой поворот

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть парент который все время поворачиваеться, и в него могу я сувать объекты, но только один, т.е. удалил добавил, удалил, добавил, суть ясна, но мне нужно что бы добавлении нового у него был поворот такой же как и в удаленного, что я только не делал с поворотами ичего не выходит , вот код объекта:

```
GameObject _go = Instantiate(Objects[number], ParentTransform);
    _go.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
```

не работает, как можно по другому?

Update: Мне нужно что бы при добавлении объекта в дочернии т.е. `_child.SetParent (_Parent)`, у дочернего объекта был поворот 0 относительно родителя т.е. что бы он был повернут так же как и повернут родитель

Answer (score -1):

Если ты хочешь нулевой поворот относительно мира:

1. добавляешь обьект без родительского обьекта. Просто в мир.
2. transform.rotation = new Quaterion(0,0,0,0); //поворот равен нулю
3. добавляешь как чайлда
4. `trasform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0);` //ставим обьект в нулевую точку

---

Если ты хочешь нулевой поворот чайлда относительно родителя:

1. Добавляешь чайлд-обьект
2. `trasform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0);` //ставим обьект в нулевую точку
3. `transform.rotation = new Quaterion(0,0,0,0);` //поворот равен нулю

Comment: Все бы хорошо, но кватернион конструируется от 4х float'ов, исправь, будь добр.

Comment: такой же эффект как и с простым new Vector3(0,0,0);

Comment: @k0vpack у меня работает. Ты уверен что ты добавляешь как дочерний обьект? Проследи где твой обьект после добавление через инспектор обьектов на сцене.

Comment: @Andrew я добавляю его кодом, и при интстантиейте сразу указываю родителя, но почему-то разворот объекта равен развороту родителя

Comment: так и должно быть. Проапдейтил ответ. Если ответ не отображает то что ты хотел увидеть, обнови вопрос свой так, что бы стало понятно достаточно однозначно что ты хочешь получить. Если нужно -- со скриншотами.

Comment: @Andrew обновил

Comment: на обновленный вопрос мой изначальный ответ подходил)

Comment: @Andrew странно, но оно так не работает, после добавления и изменения rotation у чилда, в инспекторе же его значения вообще кривое, даже менял локал ротейшн

Comment: так ты же говоришь что ротейшн у чайлда должен быть такой же как у крутящегося родителя. Хорошо обдумай вопрос и потом его напиши заново. Прям с нуля.